# How to move elements on scroll-down with scrolling down the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

Please look at this [website](http://makeyourmoneymatter.org/).  as you see in some sections, when you scroll down the page, the actual page is not going down, only the elements and images start moving for taking some effect. I did my best to implement such thing but I failed how do I can implement such thing (specially taking the effect)?

Comment: Helo Drupalisht ,can u please share code if u dont mind?

Comment: Something like this might help a bit : [Click](http://johnpolacek.github.io/superscrollorama/)

Comment: I thought makeyourmoneymatter.org ,is your site ,and you are asking why it doesnt scroll like in All webpages.

Comment: @PratikJoshi I know nothing about Parralax scrolling

Answer (score 1):

A very nice site, and a very good example of **Parallax Scrolling**.

Achieving a site just like that is going to take a long time, but you can start by looking at some parallax sites [here](http://www.desiznworld.com/2013/07/free-jquery-parallax-scrolling-plugins.html), to get an idea of the source code and look through some demo's.